# GWT Deferred Binding method call

Tags: gwt

Is it possible to use GWT deferred binding to make a method invocation of a class?

I've developed a GWT application whereby web pages forms UI widgets are generated using property files instead of coding them in Java.

Using sample property file below, my intention of using Java like reflection in GWT is so that if btnSave is clicked in a form, it will invoke validateAddress() method inside FormValidator.java to perform UI validation on address fields

**Sample Property file**

```
txtAddress.UiType=TextField
btnSave.Title=Save
btnSave.UiType=Button
btnSave.onClick=com.sample.form.validation.FormValidator.validateAddress()
```

**FormValidator.java**

```
public boolean validateAddress(){
   ...(validation code)
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how that might look and work? Some kinds of limited reflection are possible to generate so that deferred binding provides them, but I'm not sure what a "method call to a static class" means here, or "method name provided from a generator's method argument", given that all generator methods are called at compile time, not runtime...

Comment: The following code below is an example of Java method invocation of testMethod() from SomeClass.java through reflection. Can this form of reflection be achieved in GWT?  `Class<?> c = Class.forName(SomeClass.class); Class[] argTypes = new Class[] { String[].class }; Method methodName = c.getDeclaredMethod("testMethod", argTypes); <pre> <code>String[] mainArgs = Arrays.copyOfRange(args, 1, args.length); main.invoke(null, (Object)mainArgs);`

Comment: Yes, I know how Java itself does it, but for reasons that are probably clear to you, that won't work in GWT. Can you edit the question for how you would expect the GWT you are trying to design to work, so we can try to build an answer based on that?

Comment: Hi Colin, I've edited my question. I hope this might give you some picture of the requirement I need